# Affecting Sass variable with a Knockout bind or other solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, sass

Is it possible to change a sass variable by data-bind?

Example: I want to change the color of a variable with a button.

I'm open to other solutions besides Knockout.js.

```css
$color: red;

my_class {
  background-color: $color;
  
  height:20px
  width:20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-bind="css: { $color: 'green'}">Change to Green</button>


<div class="my_class"></div
```

Answer (score 2):

SASS is a CSS preprocessor and during SASS files compilation replaces every occurance of the variable (`$color`) with it's exact value (`red`).

Thus you can not affect this after SASS has been compiled into CSS.

You can use style binding

```
<div data-bind="style: { color: currentProfit() < 0 ? 'red' : 'black' }">
   Profit Information
</div>
```

as described in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) in order to change color of the specisic element.

Or you can return this color from your view model and use this in the style binding.

Comment: Since Less doesn't need compilation to run, do you think it could be an advantage on working with knockout compared to Sass?

Comment: Unfortunately, Less is also compiled into CSS, and this approach will not work.